# Rails - CSS not loaded in internet explorer

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, stylesheet

I've been struggling for weeks trying to fix this problem, but I haven't found the solution.
My [webpage](http://sharehomme.com) works great on both Chrome and Firefox, but not on all versions of internet explorer. Apparently, there were many questions complaining about the same issue but I still haven't solved my problem after trying all the known solutions. Here is some info for you.

1. The webpage(application) is based on Ruby on Rails.
2. I have few enough css files; they don't exceed the "31-limit"
3. On top of page, I define `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`
4. Passes the W3C validation

The stylesheet, *posts.css.scss* contains..

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

and even this simple styling is not applied when someone views the webpage via internext explorer.

I've been using Firebug and Chrome debugging tools to find the source of problem, but haven't come up with success yet. I'd appreciate any help for this.

Comment: Could you be running into the 4096 selector per file limit (remember that by default rails is combining all your css into one file. )

Comment: @FrederickCheung, could you tell me how I can check it?

Comment: Still trying to solve this problem..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are indeed over the 4096 selector per file limit for IE.  You are at 5775 according to [CSS: Selector Counter](http://snippet.bevey.com/css/selectorCount.php).  It appears that others have used this solution to get around the 4096 selector limitations: [ChristianPeters CSS Split tool for IE 4096 Limit](https://gist.github.com/2398394#file_lib_css_splitter.rb).

Another tool that appears to be a little more formal and documented:
[CSSSplitter](https://github.com/zweilove/css_splitter)

Let me know if one of these does the job.

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I got rid of the number of CSS selectors by excluding unnecessary stuff from my css files (I was importing bootstrap in some stylesheets unnecessarily)